# I never use PDO serialize or unrealize. But I got this error: 'You cannot serialize or unserialize PDO instances'

Tags: php, symfony, serialization, pdo, fatal-error

I never use PDO on my project, especially serialize and unserialize. But I got this error.

> Fatal error: Class
>   'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\FlattenException' not found in
>   /var/www/test/mikroskil/mikroweb/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/ExceptionListener.php
>   on line 56 Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'You cannot serialize or unserialize PDO instances' in [no active
>   file]:0 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: PDO->__sleep() #1
>   [internal function]: session_write_close() #2 {main} thrown in [no
>   active file] on line 0

it's so frustrating. Anybody can help me? It appears suddenly when i refresh my page.

Note :
I have an error before.
I use a form with POST method. And then i put a session on it.
After that, i got this error.

> failed to start the session: already started by php ($_session is
>   set).

I tried to fix that error. But suddenly the page is showing this error

> Fatal error: Class
>   'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\FlattenException' not found in
>   /var/www/test/mikroskil/mikroweb/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/ExceptionListener.php
>   on line 56 Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'You cannot serialize or unserialize PDO instances' in [no active
>   file]:0 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: PDO->__sleep() #1
>   [internal function]: session_write_close() #2 {main} thrown in [no
>   active file] on line 0

Comment: That's correct, you can't serialize a datatype of resource, same as you can't serialize a filehandle; but it looks like you're trying to store something in session that includes a resource

Comment: Yeah. And I have solve this.

Comment: I just clear my browser cookies :) Thanks

Comment: about the $Session is already set , this happens because you already have initialized the session somewhere previously in the code, so the session cookie has already been sent in the headers and therefore you cannot initiate the session again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found this answer.
You just need to clear your Cookies on your browser.
Maybe the previous error has been create a cookies and cannot replace it.
i try to clear all my browser cookies and it successfull !

:)

Comment: It's not a solution actually. If a request crashes your application - then there is an issue with application.

Comment: can you give me an example about that request? I have read some comments. They told the same. That erorrs appears when the script try to store something in session that includes a resource. So, i try to clear my browser cache and cookies. And it works on me.

Comment: "can you give me an example about that request?" --- well, it is exactly that request that crashed your application. Have you seen stackoverflow.com crashing from your request that required clearing caches? Or may be gmail.com?

Comment: umm, never. but i have seen the other web page that load steadily, but nothing in that page. But it can load after clearing the cache.

Comment: "umm, never" --- so, it probably means, that it's how applications should behave isn't it? I mean, if your application requires you to clear *cookies* (oops confused with "caches" lol) then there is something wrong with your app.

Comment: oohh, i see. thanks alot. But i need to ask you another thing. Is possible to have more than one controller in a view(html.twig) ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27810785/having-more-than-one-controller-in-one-view-in-symfony

Comment: to be honest with you guys, some migrations/application updates requires dropping sessions which also fix the problem, and yes this is something which gmail/stackoverflow does occasionaly when needed

Answer (score 4):

I have recently had this issue and the problem was I was storing my model on session (which has active pdo connection inside) and when the request is done, php automatically try to serialize $_SESSION to store on tmp file.

The main problem is PDO connection can not be serialized. If you encounter this issue, you need to check where do you serialize any object that contains active pdo connection.

Comment: This is the right answer. I just experienced the same thing by trying to store a class with a private PDO object in $_SESSION.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same error when using Medoo PHP Framework, I realized **you cannot encode(serialize) a PDOStatement instances**.

In my case I was using **PHP json_encode** to encode data to be sent to my appliction and part of that data contained the **PDOStatement instances - data returned after executing a database operation**. I just removed the PDOStatement instances from my data and everything worked okay.

Answer (score -3):

I got this too but reading this question and, especially, zerkms responses helped me locate the problem in my code. Clearing one's cache is not an appropriate response to the problem! Having recently re-vamped my classes to use dependency-injection (?), storing them as session variables is no longer appropriate.

Comment: Kindly Edit your Answer

Comment: What **exactly** did you do to solve the problem? Are you sure you've used Symfony without dependency injection before? And what do you mean by that connection to the session?

Comment: My problem was that I was trying to save a model with a db connection in a session variable, hence the 'You cannot serialize or unserialize PDO instances'  error.