# Having more than one controller in one view in Symfony?

Tags: html, symfony, controller, twig

Can someone explain to me about this?
can we have more than one controller in one view (html.twig) in Symfony?

If it can using multiple controller in a view, how to use it? Can give me an example how to

Comment: Views don't know anything about controllers. So it's not clear what your whole question means.

Comment: i tried to use a view for two controller, but it doesnt work. And it make me hestitate. Now i use the same controller and handle it with filtering the user role.

Comment: "but it doesnt work" --- it's not helpful

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to use render. Here's the documentation & example:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers

Comment: I know. But i have tried to use render to destination html.twig. but it doesn't work. But i have found how to trick that. I use the same controller and check the user role.